# Why we are using Spring:bind path in jsp what is the use

Tags: spring, jsp

> What is the use of **Spring bind:path** and why we use it

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation and/or consulting the almighty google?

Comment: @tnw I read that it used to evaluate the bean property and bind while rendering

Comment: @lakshmidhanapal Sounds like you just answered your own question.

Comment: take a good action with this question please (delete)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a general reference question that can be answered by reading product documentation

Answer (score 0):

[Use the force, read the source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.x/taglib/tag/BindTag.html)

> The `spring:bind` tag provides you with support for evaluation of the status of a certain bean or bean property. The status of a bean includes the value of the actual bean or bean property you're evaluating as well as possibly available errors and the expression to use in forms in order for the databinding functionality to be able to bind the properties again when submitting for instance a form.